# packages.config file is ignored during Visual Studio Build and nuget restore commands

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, packages.config

I am trying to setup automated nuget package restoration on a vs build or command line build.
When following the specified Microsoft article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrate-to-automatic-package-restore-visual-studio

I am unable to get Visual Studio 2019 or the following commands (nuget restore mysolution.sln, msbuild -t:restore, msbuild -restore) to read from a packages.config file in each of my projects

I have tried the following:

- removing any references to PackageReference in each of the project files
- deleting the bin and obj folders in each project
- adding a local nuget.config with the following:
- deleting the local packages folder
- deleting the global packages folder
- running the following command: nuget locals all -clear
- Updated Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager and set "Allow Nuget to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual" and set the Default Package management format to "Packages.config"
- Restarting Visual Studio a few times.

When I run the nuget restore command for my solution it attempts to restore from packagereference inside each of the project files but since I do not have any it does nothing but still creates the corresponding nuget.g.props and project.assets.json files. I cannot use packagereferences inside of project files since this is not portable to other projects.

I require the ability to use packages.config file with one of the build commands.
I am stumped as to why this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete the `.vs` hidden folder from the solution folder, it still restores the old nuget management format **PackageReference**, and still use it.

Try the following steps:

**1)** Close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder and every `bin` and `obj` folder.

**2)** make sure the every `packages.config` is in the project folder so that it will work.

**3)** If you use your own nuget.config, please make sure its package source contains all the nuget packages. Or the file is redundant, you should remove it and then [add the nuget package source under VS IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

**3)** restart VS, run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

**4)** After that, you can delete global nuget folder and local nuget folder and then run `nuget restore xxx.sln` to check it.

---

EDIT: Make sure your project is *not* an SDK-style project; SDK projects are not supported with packages.config files (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format)).

Comment: Qian - I went through these steps and it did not work. When running the command update-package -reinstall I get "No package updates are available from the current package source for project" and I get the same messages when running nuget restore solutionfile.sln. Based on the output it is still looking for the projectreference entries even though I have none.

Comment: Did you make sure the `packages.config` is in the project folder, and is your project a non-sdk project style? After remove every `PackageReference` node, save,close vs, delete `.vs`, `bin`,`obj` folder, restart project, add packages.config into the project folder, run `update-package -reinstall`. Also, I have tested in my side without any problems that change `PackgeReference` format into `Packages.config` format. My project is net framework4.8 non-sdk project. Only non-sdk project can use `packages.config`.See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzqXv.png).

Comment: Thanks for that last piece of information. I could not find any information on where only non-sdk projects are supported with packages.config. I am using .net standard and .net Core. How would this work on cross platform products? Per the documentation, you are unable to using PackageReference on Mono based project.